# Angular JS custom textbox from a list validation

Tags: html, angularjs, validation

I am creating dynamic textboxes from a list like the following

**Angular js**

```
$scope.phonenumbers = [{text: ''},{text: ''},{text: ''}];
```

HTML Part

```
<div class="relativeWrap" ng-repeat="phone in phonenumbers">
     <input placeholder="Phone Number" pattern="[0-9]{10}" ng-maxlength="10" maxlength="10" type="text" class="form-control input-text phone_number" name="phonenumber[]" ng-model="phone.text" >
</div>
```

Now I need to do the following validation in form

1. Any one of the following 3 textboxes is mandatory. I put `required` but it is validating all.

Please help

Comment: your problem is not clear at all

Comment: validation will work on submit, where is your form tag submit button etc. add that code too and few more details

Comment: i got a list and from that list I am creating 3 textboxes in a form. I needs to validate the textboxes on form submit. Like any one of the textbox is mandatory. ie user can fill any one, not all. Only one in the 3 is mandatory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use ng-required and conditionally set the required to true for all the field only when none of the fields have a value. To do this you will need to maintain a flag in your controller and bind that your ng-required.

The method in the controller:

```
$scope.isValue = false;

$scope.textChange = function(){
    $scope.isNoValue = $scope.phonenumbers.some(function(item)){
          return item.text;
     }
}
```

Your HTML:

```
<div class="relativeWrap" ng-repeat="phone in phonenumbers">
     <input placeholder="Phone Number" pattern="[0-9]{10}" ng-maxlength="10" maxlength="10" type="text" class="form-control input-text phone_number" name="phonenumber[]" ng-model="phone.text" ng-required="!isValue" ng-change="textChange">
</div>
```